# ASP.NET Opening File in Zip Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to create a zip folder and add a simple text file to it using my ASP.Net app running on .NET 4.6.1.  I keep getting an error thrown and I have no idea how to correct it.  The error is a result of trying to open the Readme.txt file.  I have marked in the code where I am seeing the error.  I notice that when trying to open the readmeEntry variable that it has Length and CompressedLength showing error 'System.InvalidOperationException'.

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel, Boolean)'.'

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(path + "\\" + reportFileNameZip, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true))
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry("Readme." + "txt");
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
        {
           writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
        }
    }  //ERROR MESSAGE //
}
```

Comment: I just ran your code from a console app. It works fine. How did you add a reference to System.IO.Compression? It somehow looks like the version of the reference added and the one being used do not match

Comment: @PraveenPaulose ya I think it is an issue because I'm using ASP.net.  I downloaded it from Nuget Manager.

Comment: From NuGet? That package isn't officially in Nuget. Use the add reference dialog

Comment: I downloaded System.IO.Compression.ZipFile

Comment: @JohnDoe I checked this in ASP.NET MVC too. Works fine. Can you check the version of your assembly in References and bin > Debug folder

Comment: Tried to regenerate on 4.6.1 using nuget package, it is working fine.
 My System.IO.Compression version is 4.3.0.
 Btw, why do you need System.IO.Compression.ZipFile?

Comment: Boom!  Ya I just needed to add the Compression reference.  Thanks everyone i was pulling my hair out on this one.